# default option not displaying in Angular 8 reactive form

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have an Angular 8 reactive form using Bootstrap 4. I can't get the select element to display the default option. I've put the default option first and added 'selected' but it still doesn't display. I have to manually choose the 'Select Country' option to get it to display.

Here is my code:

```
<label for="countryCode">Country Code<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<select formControlName="countryCode" class="form-control">
   <option selected>Select Country</option>
   <option *ngFor="let country of Countries" [value]="country.countryCode">
     {{ country.countryCode }} - {{ country.countryName }}
   </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Please show how you are setting up the form in your component?

Comment: the code works in isolation as it is - any console errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simillar example to display default option in select list.

try this, i have used in my project and it works.

// template

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select formControlName="status">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Select Status</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of statusList" 
            [ngValue]="option">{{option.label}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

// component

```
statusList = [{ id: 1, label: 'Active' }, { id: 2, label: 'InActive' }];
form = new FormGroup({
  status: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Worked on angular 12, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4njza)**

bind selected value with   `<select [(value)]="selected">`

**.html**

```
<label for="countryCode">Country Code<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<select formControlName="countryCode" class="form-control" [(value)]="selected" >
   <option value="selectCountry">Select Country</option>
   <option *ngFor="let country of Countries" [value]="country.countryCode">
     {{ country.countryCode }} - {{ country.countryName }}
   </option>
 </select>
```

add selected value in `.ts` file  like this

```
selected = 'selectCountry';
```

Hope this will helps ...!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<label for="countryCode">Country Code<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<select formControlName="countryCode" class="form-control">
   <option value=null>Select Country</option>
   <option *ngFor="let country of Countries" [value]="country.countryCode">
     {{ country.countryCode }} - {{ country.countryName }}
   </option>
 </select>
```

In ts :

```
this.form=this.formbuilder.group({
    countryCode:[null,[Validators]]
)}
```